# Symfony 3.3 Dependency Injection changes

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

In Synfony 3.3, the new best practice for DI

> is to use normal constructor dependency injection (or "action"
>   injection in controllers) instead of fetching public services via
>   $this->get() (though that does still work)

[as seen in offical documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#controllers-are-registered-as-services)

So no need to specify services as we can type hint them in class controllers :

```
class InvoiceMailer
{
    private $generator;

    public function __construct(InvoiceGenerator $generator)
    {
        $this->generator = $generator
    }

    // ...
}
```

This seems to work well, but what if I extends a class and add more parameters in my constructors ???

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

class MyClass extends HttpException
{
    private $generator;

    public function __construct(InvoiceGenerator $generator, \Exception $previous = null, array $headers = [], $code = 0)
    {
        $this->generator = $generator;
        $statusCode      = $generator->getStatusCode();
        $message         = $generator->getTitle();

        parent::__construct($statusCode, $message, $previous, $headers, $code);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Now I get a circular reference error :

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceCircularReferenceException]
>   Circular reference detected for service "AppBundle\Service\MyClass", path: "AppBundle\Service\MyClass -> AppBundle\Service\MyClass".

So, what is the best practice in this case ??

Thanks.

Comment: If I had to guess then I suspect your InvoiceGenerator is somehow dependent on HttpException.  Or perhaps whatever you are injecting MyClass into.

Comment: Exception should not be a services. See "exclude" in [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html#controllers-are-registered-as-services). Here is [config example with "exclude"](https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/blob/fe457d0bba80033d34b18ca728f8a291e0343ebc/packages/Statie/src/config/services.yml#L8)

Answer (score 1):

For that case you might have to define the service explicitly as `\Exception $previous` argument in fact is parent class of `MyClass` (through `HttpException`) so the autowiring method try to inject/create an instance of `MyClass` again on this argument, result: "Circular Reference".

This is an abstraction of what happens to you:

```
namespace App\Foo;

class MyClass extends \Exception
{
    public function __construct(\Exception $previous = null)
    {
    }
}
```

Same error, so you can to solve it passing a `null` value to this argument:

```
# service.yml
services:
    # ...
    App\Foo\MyClass: 
        $previous: ~
```

or changing its definition manually in a compiler pass or DI extension.